# Graphql Clients with Axios-like interceptors

Tags: axios, graphql

I'm working with Graphql but I'm having trouble finding the equivalent of [Axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) for Graphql clients. I've checked Apollo, Relay and Graphql Request clients but none of them seem to be able to intercept responses/requests.

The reason why I need interceptors is because when my access token expires, my API will spit out a header indicating it has expired. So then:

- I want to check the response has the specific 'token-expired' header
- Hit my refresh endpoint to get a new token
- Redo the request with the new token

I realise I could probably just use Axios to connect to my Graphql API, but I just thought I'd ask if there's a way to achieve this with any of the popular graphql clients before as it seems weird there wouldn't be.

Comment: apollo-link-token-refresh

Comment: @xadm thanks for the suggestion but my token is Httponly, so I can't actually do that from the frontend.

Comment: retry link, custom link ... apollo links as a kind of solution

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#retrying-operations